# How to pass variable into a setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my attend:

```
  $('md-card').each(function(index){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $(this).addClass('hietim');
    },500*index);
  });
```

The goal is to have a hierarchical timing for the `md-card` elements.

It didn't work because `$(this)` means nothing inside the `setTimeout(function(){})`. I also tried:

```
  $('md-card').each(function(index){
    var e = $(this)
    setTimeout(function(e){
      e.addClass('hietim');
    },500*index);
  });
```

It will pop a jquery error. Also tried:

```
  $('md-card').each(function(index){
    $(this).delay(500*index).addClass('hietim');
  });
```

It fails because `delay()` doesn't seem to work with `addClass`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second option should work as long as you don't pass the variable into the function. It will then pass a reference to `e` creating a closure which will allow the function to use that variable when the setTimeout finishes regardless of whether or not that scope continues to exist.

```
$('md-card').each(function(index){
var e = $(this)
setTimeout(function(){  // Remove the e here
  e.addClass('hietim');
},500*index);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Even you can try this way also

```
$('md-card').each(function(index){
setTimeout(function(thisObj){
  thisObj.addClass('hietim');
},500*index,$(this));
});
```

Take a look clarification of [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function detail here.

Answer (score -1):

For this purpose I used the element's offset (from top and left).

You can see the source code of my [jQuery plugin](http://zavoloklom.github.io/material-design-hierarchical-display/) on [github](https://github.com/zavoloklom/material-design-hierarchical-display/blob/master/js/jquery.zmd.hierarchical-display.js#L46).

```
$('md-card').each(function(index){
    var element = $(this);
    var elementOffset = element.position();
    var calculatedOffset = elementOffset.left * 0.8 + elementOffset.top;
    var timeOut = parseFloat(calculatedOffset / 15).toFixed(2);
    setTimeout(function(){
        element.addClass('hietim');
    }, timeOut*index);
});
```